# Font issue in PHP server

Tags: php, mysql, fonts

I have transferred on of my website from Centos to Hostinger, I imported the database, after that the font is not readable. The language is Malayalam its shows like (à´¸à´¨àµà´¤àµ‹à´·àµ à´Ÿàµà´°àµ‡à´¾à´«à´¿ à´¤à´¾...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following encoding while creating the database

Database charset: utf-8

Database collation: utf8_general_ci